# Move Constructor Complaining about "non-class type"

Tags: c++

All, I'm playing around with understanding r-value, l-value and what scott meyers calls "universal references". I'm having some trouble setting up my example, shown below. Could anyone offer some guidance?

```
#include <cstdio>

namespace who_needs_namespaces {

class SomeSillyClass {
    public:
    SomeSillyClass() {
        printf("Default constructed.\n");
    }
    SomeSillyClass(const SomeSillyClass& rhs) {
        printf("L-Value constructed.\n");
    }
    SomeSillyClass(SomeSillyClass&& rhs) {
        printf("R-Value Constructed.\n");   
    }

    void doStuff() const {
        printf("doing...\n");
    }
};

template<typename T>
class HolderByValue {
public:
    HolderByValue() = delete;   
    HolderByValue(T toHold) : m_mine(toHold) 
    { }; 

private:
    T m_mine;
};

template<typename T>
class HolderByRef {
public:
    HolderByRef() = delete;   
    HolderByRef(T&& toHold) : m_mine(toHold)
    { }; 

private:
    T m_mine;
};

}

using namespace who_needs_namespaces;

int main() {
    //Check our silly class.
    SomeSillyClass defaultCtr;
    defaultCtr.doStuff();
    SomeSillyClass copyCtr(defaultCtr);
    copyCtr.doStuff();
    SomeSillyClass moveCtr(SomeSillyClass);
    moveCtr.doStuff();

    //Check our HolderByValue
    //HolderByValue<SomeSillyClass> holder(defaultCtr);
    HolderByValue<SomeSillyClass &> holder(defaultCtr);

}
```

---

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:59:13: error: request for member 'doStuff' in 'moveCtr', which is of non-class type 'who_needs_namespaces::SomeSillyClass(who_needs_namespaces::SomeSillyClass)'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `SomeSillyClass moveCtr(SomeSillyClass);`? Passing a type to a constructor? Declaraing a function... I suspect the compiler thinks the latter

Comment: Try `SomeSillyClass moveCtr((SomeSillyClass()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've fallen victim to what Scott Meyers calls C++'s Most Vexing Parse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: This is what I get for trying to be fancy. Thanks Michael and doctorlove!